# Ошибка WordPress при установке плагинов

Tags: wordpress

Возникла проблема, пробовал восстановить эти файлы из рабочего бекапа, не помогло. Подскажите, что делать в такой ситуации?

> Установка не удалась: Warning: fopen(/tmp/classic-editor.1.6.3-1PAFvS.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/u685875/data/www/dostavka-cvetov-56.ru/html/wp-includes/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 140 Warning: rename(/tmp/classic-editor.1.6.3-1PAFvS.tmp,/tmp/classic-editor.1.6.3.zip): No such file or directory in /var/www/u685875/data/www/dostavka-cvetov-56.ru/html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 1203 Warning: unlink(/tmp/classic-editor.1.6.3-1PAFvS.tmp): No such file or directory in /var/www/u685875/data/www/dostavka-cvetov-56.ru/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 333 {"success":false,"data":{"install":"plugin","slug":"classic-editor","pluginName":"Classic Editor","errorMessage":"\u0410\u0440\u0445\u0438\u0432 \u043d\u0435 \u0443\u0434\u0430\u043b\u043e\u0441\u044c \u0443\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c. PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : Missing archive file '/tmp/classic-editor.1.6.3-1PAFvS.tmp'"}}

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, что делать в такой ситуации?

Правильно настроить сервер. А именно временный каталог.

Как костыль можно применить такой способ

1. Создать в корне сайта каталог `tmp` и дать ему нужные права.
2. Прописать в конфиге `define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'tmp/' )`